# Selenium Webdriver - missing classes in maven repository

Tags: maven-2, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have been using [Selenium Webdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/09_webdriver.html) successfully with JAR downloaded from their pages or code.google. But now I would like convert my project to use Maven repository. I found out that my required classes are in support module of webdriver and [confirmed](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/#svn/trunk/support/src/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui) it in their repository ( classes Wait, WebDriverWait, ExpectedCondition). So I have linked required dependency [webdriver-support-module](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.webdriver/webdriver-support/0.9.7376) but these classes weren't here.

Can anybody explain to me why the classes from this module aren't in this module in Maven repository and tell me where I can find them? I will be really grateful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to reference each module separately, just add a whole Selenium 2.0a5 (currently the latest one) dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
    <version>2.0a5</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also find more information about using Selenium WebDriver on [their wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/UsingWebDriver). This Maven Repository also contains the latest [selenium-parent](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-parent) project / POM information.